# Google custom search element customization in Angular2

Tags: angular, google-search

I'm currently trying to integrate a Google custom search element in a dedicated Angular component; I added a  selector with usual Javascript code as mentionned in Google API doc, and the searchbox indeed displays in my page.
My problem is I need to completely change the look of this searchbox as well as search button for Material Design components.
So, first, is it possible to achieve this? If yes, how can this be done?
I hope I am clear enough...
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of your scope I think the standard API will be overly limited for your needs. In this scenario I would recommend using the [Google Search REST API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest).

Using this you can create an Angular service which makes the requests and models to act as your data transfer objects - these would match the request and response models specified in the API documentation.

Then create a new component and module, provide the new service within the module and add your markup and service calls into the component. That way you have a fully customized component that does all of the relevant communication with Google.

Comment: Hi Kallum, thank you for your reply. Indeed, the REST API seems very interesting, regarding the flexibility it offers. I don't know anything about Angular services (I'm a pure noob) but I'm digging in this direction. Thanks again!

Comment: Have a look here, this you get you started: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html

Comment: I already found that page, thanks ;-) Nevertheless something is puzzling me: I think I can use a google API npm package in my service instead of reinventing the wheel, but I don't know which one to choose among all the existing ones (sure enough ng-rest-api). What do you think about it?

Comment: @arsrobota You are free to use included JavaScript libraries in Angular2 - just install the files from something such as `npm install google-search`. You can then follow the package documentation from there. Personally I would still create your own service then make the package API calls from the service as this decouples your components from the data source. This way you could switch to a different package in the future and only change the code in your service, not your entire app.

Comment: It perfectly works! Used in conjunction with RX Observable I get search results. Thank you very much Kallum!